# Will dd command write data to a bad block of a flash chip?

Tags: linux

I want to know whether dd command will probably write data to bad block of a nand flash chip.

Our file system is ubifs, and it is based on MTD layer. And dd will read and write /dev/mtdblock2 device file. As I know ubifs will handle bad block/sector while MTD does not. So my opinion is that dd on a nand flash chip with ubifs may write data to a bad block/sector, is it right?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the flash chip. If the flash chip has inbuilt wear levelling controller then no it won't. If the flash chip is purely a chunk of flash memory without a controller then yes it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I know ubifs will handle bad block/sector while MTD does not.

Not true, MTD is also aware of bad blocks, and maintains a bad-block table.
See [MTD Bad block table support](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/tech/mtdnand/x144.html) and **drivers/mtd/nand/bbt.c**.

> So my opinion is that dd on a nand flash chip with ubifs may write data to a bad block/sector, is it right?

Your premise about MTD is incorrect, but the conclusion is true.
Also the presence of a UBIFS would be irrelevant, since **dd** operates on the block device rather than the filesystem.

The **dd** command accesses a block device, which MTD is not, so the mtdblock (which has a flash translation layer) has to be used.

The [MTD FAQ](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html) has this explicit warning regarding the use of mtdblock and NAND:

```
But think twice before using mtdblock in read-write mode.  
And don't try to use it on NAND flash as it is does not handle bad eraseblocks.
```

IOW the problem is not the **dd** program, but rather the use of the mtdblock device.

The MTD FAQ recommends the use of bad-block aware programs such as mtd-utils.

Answer (score 0):

The `dd` command will **try** to write to the sector, bad or not bad. A `dd` to the device will not care for the file system that may be present on that device. But if a write would succeed, the sector would not have been bad, as with flash memory the most common failure is that blocks can't be cleared/written.

With a magnetic disk, an overwrite may make a previously unreadable block readable again, but I would not trust important data to a sector that had developed problems before.